# Html input textfield scroll issue on windows phone

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I have phonegap app for windows phone. In that app UI is created in HTML. But there is a problem with horizontal scrolling in textfields. I want to scroll text the same way we scroll the text in any native windows phone app.
For example, the address bar textfield in IE browser on windows mobile can scroll the whole text

Here's my code:

```
<div> 
   <div style="width: 60%;float: left;margin-right: 1px;padding-left: 25px;">
       <input type="text" id="mobmake" placeholder="Mobile Make" style="background:#0B65B5;color:#FFF;margin-left: -6px;padding-left: 13px;"> 
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
   <div style="width: 60%;float: left;padding-left: 25px;">
       <input type="text" id="mobmodel" placeholder="Mobile Model" style="background:#0B65B5;color:#FFF;margin-left: -6px;padding-left: 13px;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code or other stuff you have done so far?

Comment: It just has simple html code

Comment: <div>
    <div style="width: 60%;float: left;margin-right: 1px;padding-left: 25px;">
     <input type="text" id="mobmake" placeholder="Mobile Make" style="background:#0B65B5;color:#FFF;margin-left: -6px;padding-left: 13px;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
    <div style="width: 60%;float: left;padding-left: 25px;">
     <input type="text" id="mobmodel" placeholder="Mobile Model" style="background:#0B65B5;color:#FFF;margin-left: -6px;padding-left: 13px;">
    </div>
   </div>